# python how to reassign dupilcate string values to a new string

Tags: python

- I take in a string `aabullc`
- newstring should be assigned `aall` after the loop since `a` and `l` are duplicates
- strings with more then 1 dupe like `aaabullc` should return `aaall`

  ```
  def rearrangeLetters(S):
    print(len(S))
    start = 0
    newstring = ""

    for i in range(start+1, len(S)):
        if(S[start] == S[i]):
            newstring+=S[i]
            print(newstring)
            start +=1
  ```

**issue:**

`print(newstring)` is never running

Comment: Can you make it more clear about "duplicate". E.g., if input is `aba` (non consecutive duplicates), what is the expected output? What about `aaabaaa` (duplicates more than two )?

Comment: What actually happens instead? Do you get an error? A wrong answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def rearrangeLetters(S):
    s = [S[i] for i in range(len(S))]
    newstring = ""
    for t in s:
        if s.count(t) > 1:
            
            newstring += t
    return newstring
```

call function:

```
output = rearrangeLetters("aabullc")
print(output)
```

output:

```
aall
```

Comment: This will also catch non-consecutive duplicates (which doesn't seem to be what OP wants) `rearrangeLetters('abca') -> 'aa'`. The `s.count` turns this into O(n^2) which is more complex than warranted by any interpretation of this question. I'm not sure what style you're following but it doesn't look like you've done much python and I'd recommend you read [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

Comment: Try this string - *'aablb'*

Answer (score 3):

Something like this may help you:

You can transform this easily to your function.

```
s = 'aabullc'

from itertools import groupby
result = ''

for k, g in groupby(s):
    #print(k, ''.join(g))
    ss = ''.join(g)
    if len(ss) >=2:
        result += ss    # aall
```

Comment: You can even tighten this up with a generator expression `''.join(''.join(chars) for _, g in itertools.groupby(s) if len(chars:=list(g)) > 1)` or `''.join(k*len(chars) for k, g in itertools.groupby(s) if len(chars:=list(g)) > 1)`

Comment: Agreed.  Like *warlus* is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

For short strings, can do this easily by just collecting a list of what has been seen, and *possibly* more efficiently for longer strings with the addition of a set

```py
def rearrange_letters(source_string):
    result     = []     # collection to return
    duplicated = set()  # efficient lookup for very long strings
    for index, char in enumerate(source_string):
        if char in duplicated:
            result.append(char)
        elif source_string[index:].count(char) > 1:
            duplicated.add(char)
            result.append(char)
    return "".join(result)  # NOTE join is a method of string ""
```

```py
>>> rearrange_letters("aabullc")
'aall'
>>> rearrange_letters("aaabcdc")
'aaacc'
```